# Отключение программы по условию

Tags: c++

Есть условие.

```
if (a + c == b) {
    x1 = c / a;
    printf("x1=1\nx2=%Lf, t.k. a+b=c", x1);
}
exit(0);
```

Нужно, чтобы при данном условии программа отключалась.

Comment: Мало понятен смысл вопроса. Проясните.

Comment: В чем ошибка?

Comment: Синтаксис?

Comment: Эээ.. Ну наверное, нужно внести exit() в операторные скобки if'а.

Comment: нет. я все понял

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно добавить подходящий заголовок и поместить вызов в тело функции...

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    if (0 == 0) {
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Как сделать чтобы выход задержался?

Comment: В каком смысле?

Comment: на экране.

Comment: Функция sleep или getch.

Comment: понятно...

Comment: bytе, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
//сделай так
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
if(0==0){
cin.get();
return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: можно и через getch

Comment: и через sleep

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о C Builder, то: **Application->Terminate();**

Comment: нет. wx dev

Comment: Но все равно спасибо.